# Get Weekday Month Starts On in c# is showing a wrong day

Tags: c#, date, datetime-format

I created a function to get the day of the week but something strange is happening. Check the code below in Class_Global.cs

```
public static string GetWeekdayMonthStartsOn(int iMonth, int iYear)
{
    var FirstDay = new DateTime(iYear, iMonth, 1);
    int day = (int)FirstDay.DayOfWeek;

    // just to test
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Date=[" + FirstDay + "]<br>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("int day of week=[" + day + "]<br>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("FirstDay Week Name=[" + FirstDay.ToString("dddd") + "]<br>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("FirstDay Month Name=[" + FirstDay.ToString("MMMM") + "]<br>");

    return day.ToString ();
}
```

When I run the following in test.aspx from my localhost:

```
    Class_Agenda.GetWeekdayMonthStartsOn(1, 2106);
    Class_Agenda.GetWeekdayMonthStartsOn(2, 2106);
    Class_Agenda.GetWeekdayMonthStartsOn(3, 2106);
    Class_Agenda.GetWeekdayMonthStartsOn(4, 2106);
    Class_Agenda.GetWeekdayMonthStartsOn(5, 2106);
```

it returns the following wich looks like ok. Bit pay attention to the first day of March 2016 should be Tuesday and NOT monday....

> FirstDay=[1/1/2106 12:00:00 AM]
>  day=[5]
>  day=[Friday]
>   day=[January]
>  FirstDay=[2/1/2106 12:00:00 AM]
>  day=[1]
>   day=[Monday]
>  day=[February]
>  FirstDay=[3/1/2106 12:00:00
>   AM]
>  day=[1]
>  day=[Monday]
>  day=[March]
>   FirstDay=[4/1/2106 12:00:00 AM]
>  day=[4]
>  day=[Thursday]
>   day=[April]
>  FirstDay=[5/1/2106 12:00:00 AM]
>  day=[6]
>   day=[Saturday]
>  day=[May]

I appreciate if someone can help.

Comment: 2106 != 2016 - look at your code

Comment: I just figure it out!!  thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 6):

But March 1, **2106** is a Monday (see: http://www.calendar-12.com/calendar/2106).